# Cannot use token in WSO2 APIM with custom certificate

Tags: wso2, ssl-certificate, token, wso2-api-manager

I a trying to deploy WSO2 API manager (APIM) with a custom valid certificate and to use the option to encrypt in the DB token and secret user information.

I can use my certificate all right, its green even in chrome and everything will work: token emission, api consomption with a token and token revocation.  But, as soon as I try to use the option to [encrypt tokens](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Encrypting+OAuth+Keys) I get an error when trying to use the token.  Token expired.  If I push the logging to DEBUG level, nothing unusual happens but for the token being considered expired and APIM returns expired credentials.

Any one know how to use this options ?  And yes, I have tried to set that option from the get go to make sure is active before any user, api, tenant or anything else is created on the server.  If I deactivate it, every thing works normally for subscription taken after deactivation.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you generated any tokens before enable token encryption? Also, Can you add the exact error response you are getting?

Comment: I have tried both.  But, I just redid it using ansible.  Configuration are pushed before the manager is started for the first time.  I get the answer : ``` <ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
  <ams:code>900901</ams:code>
  <ams:message>Invalid Credentials</ams:message>
  <ams:description>Access failure for API: /t/test.vdm/PE/v1.0, version: v1.0. Make sure your have given the correct access token</ams:description>
</ams:fault>``` from the server.  Ill put the logs in a second comment.

Comment: Highly redacted log: ```TID: [-1] [] [2016-10-10 15:28:24,427] ERROR {...TokenPersistenceTask} -  Error occurred while persisting access token :24f7a1bab4fae90e4d558b675666cf32 {...TokenPersistenceTask}
....IdentityOAuth2Exception: Invalid request
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.storeAccessToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:244)
  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-10-10 15:28:39,917] ERROR {...} -  Invalid OAuth Token : Invalid access token {...}
TID: [1] [] [2016-10-10 15:28:39,926] @test.vdm [1] [AM] WARN ....} -  API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials ```

Comment: You can see two log files [here](http://crypto.cs.mcgill.ca/~simonpie/WSO2/)

Comment: Could it be that more modification are to be done to identity.xml ?  The documentation just says to modify the `<TokenPersistenceProcessor>` tag, but there are many other fields that look very pertinent to change.  Especially since I am using an external mysql server.

Comment: Whle generating this custom certificate, did you add `data encipherment` property to it? Otherwise the certificate can not be used to encrypt the data. But the server tries to decrypt.